# Changing the Xcode Project to new system doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Working project shifted to new system it is showing error

error: /Raja Projects/Special Build/Oct 24 2_30PM/ACE_SPE/ACE_SPE/ACE_HK/Resource's/Image's/All Image's/en.lproj/change_english_icon.png: No such file or directory

But this is the old path. My system is not having the path. What should i do. The change_english_icon.png is there in folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the relativeness of file path in "Identity and type" section of File inspector (at the right panel in XCode 4.x, View => Utilities => Show file inspector).
Seems you have something like `Absolute path` set for `Location`.

To avoid this (if the cause was absolute path or like that) make sure you have "Relative to group" or "Relative to project" or something like that set for Location in file inspector. And easy way to fix that would be to re-add missing-in-project files to project.

Answer (score 0):

THis error occurs because your project gets failed to find **change_english_icon.png** in your new system. You just only need change_english_icon.png image. **Add this image** in your project & don't forget to check the tickmark given at **copy items into destination group's folder**.

Comment: i tried this still showing the same error. The images are already in xcode. i deleted and added again. but no way......